# Can the firmware on STM32F4 be updated through USB without toggling Boot0?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32f4, bootloader

I've designed a device using a STM32F439 and would like to have a PC application where the user can update the firmware of the device.

My firmware developer has told me the we would need to give the user access to the Boot0 pin.

By default Boot0&1 are pulled low but can the MCU be reset into Bootloader mode through software without having to touch any jumpers etc?

Comment: Why don't you make a custom bootloader (i.e. your firmware) and then flash using USB?

Comment: Read about the STM32 USB DFU (device firmware upgrade) protocol (a.k.a DfuSe).

Comment: You can typically figure out how to jump into the factory bootloader from your loaded application program; of course, either that or a custom bootloader depends on your custom code being *somewhat* functional or it won't be possible to reach the factory bootloader.  Being able to activate the boot mode pin provides a path around a broken load of the custom program which the pure software solution does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can jump from the firmware to the bootloader on the STM32F4. The STM32F4 has a built in bootloader at address 0x01ff000. Here is a tutorial on how to jump https://stm32f4-discovery.net/2017/04/tutorial-jump-system-memory-software-stm32/. Once in bootloader mode you can use DfuSe form ST(free) to flash the new firmware.

Comment: This is the correct answer; I've used this method on a few projects.